# sed OSX command not working in Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, sed

The following command was written for OSX but I cannot figure out how to port this to Ubuntu.

I receive the error as listed below

### Error

`sed: -e expression #1, char 74: unterminated 's' command`

### Command

`sed -i '0,/ExecStart=/s//Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs"\n&/' /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`

Comment: It does not throw an error for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The error seems to indicate a missing `/` in the substitution command `s/search/replace/`. However, your command looks complete and runs flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on `Ubuntu server 16.04` with `GNU sed 4.2.2` and the command does what it is meant to do: insert the specified text, on a line by itself, before the first line encountered that starts with `ExecStart=`. If the line contains `ExecStart=` but not at the beginning, the line gets split and the specified text inserted at the end of the line preceding `ExecStart=`.

Better demonstrated by examples:

```
$ cat 10-kubeadm.conf
Line001
ExecStart=A
ExecStart=B
Line004
$ sed -i '0,/ExecStart=/s//Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs"\n&/' 10-kubeadm.conf
$ cat 10-kubeadm.conf
Line001
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs"
ExecStart=A
ExecStart=B
Line004
```

And:

```
$ cat 10-kubeadm.conf
Line001
Line002 ExecStart=A
Line003 ExecStart=B
Line004
$ sed -i '0,/ExecStart=/s//Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs"\n&/' 10-kubeadm.conf
$ cat 10-kubeadm.conf
Line001
Line002 Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs"
ExecStart=A
Line003 ExecStart=B
Line004
```

Comment: is it possible the previous command `sudo sed -i '/ swap / s/^\(.*\)$/#\1/g' /etc/fstab` affects this ?  I am running a vagrant machine with a bento ubuntu 16.04 server image . . . https://gist.github.com/lizrice/69d3b28979391287176b3b7155a327b9

Comment: @AranFreel It shouldn't: this command looks fine and doesn't affect anything other than your `/etc/fstab`. Please run each command separately, in order to locate the origin of the issue.